# Tray icon can't be clicked when running Delphi program as Citrix seamless application

Tags: delphi, citrix, trayicon, jedi

I use the Jedi library and the component JvTrayIcon. It works fine. But when the program is run as a Citrix seamless application, the program doesn't receive any click events.
I have search a lot but found only something about task bar icons and Delphi (Borland). I use Delphi 2010.
Has anyone experience with this problem?

--Martin

Comment: Which messages does that tray notification listen to for clicks?

Comment: A set of messages, and some adapting to Windows version
http://jvcl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jvcl/trunk/jvcl/run/JvTrayIcon.pas?view=log

Comment: It seems to use ReadProcessMemory for icon positioning. That perhaps would not get marshalled in Citrix ?

Comment: @David Hefferman, it uses OnClick and OnDblClick. And has a popup menu attached.

Comment: ReadProcessMemory?! Oh dear that's utterly lame. There's no need for that.

Comment: @user1611655 You talk about *events*, procedures of your program that the component calls. David talked about *messages* - integer constants that Windows GDI layer enqueues for the component reporting user activity. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943.aspx

Comment: Does the built-in [Delphi TTrayIcon](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeSamples/en/TTrayIcon_(Delphi)) as used in the linked example work?

Comment: @David it is inherited from RxLib times, where one needed source-level compatibility from 16-bit Delphi 1 through to Delphi 5. I don't know exactly what it is for - there is URL of some article but i did not looked - but perhaps they had their reasons. Tray API is poor thing, and probably in earlier Windows it is even worse. However, for what io remember, starting with Delphi 5 there is stock VCL component and using RxLib/JediVCL might be avoided ?

Comment: @arioch notification icon api passes coords in the messages it sends

Comment: Well, David, the link is above, if you wish - you may just grep it and make more informed suggestions. I just don't know and am not too interested either.

Comment: @arioch I would simply ditch the component and use something more sane. I also have no interest in studying it.

Comment: @LU RD, I will test it tomorrow.

Comment: There is nothing currently logged in the jedi issue tracker that would cover this situation.  Citrix and the "readprocessmemory" hack in JvTrayIcon do seem to be incompatible from what I can see.

Comment: I tested the D2010 standard Tray icon, and everything I need, works; hover, and clicks.

Comment: @WarrenP well, if you request it, then #5963 :-)

Comment: @LURD - it seems one of us should post the answer to use stock VCL trayicon ;-)

Comment: @Arioch'The, answer posted, thanks.

Comment: @Arioch 'The: ReadProcessMemory is only called if you use the TTrayIconEnumerator class yourself or if you call RefreshTray or TJvTrayIcon.GetIconRect explicitly. None of them are used by the component itself. So it can't be a problem with ReadProcessMemory as it isn't called.

Comment: @AndreasHausladen We did not saw code of the topic starter, and it seems none of us uses Citrix. So we can only trust that it failed for him.

Those class and method are provided and are not discouraged. 
BTW, there is also procedure RefreshTray using the enumerator.

But well, i have to admit that reducing JVCL in both depth and width is kinda idee fixe to me last years :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `jvcl` tray icon, I suggest using the built in [Delphi TTrayIcon](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeSamples/en/TTrayIcon_%28Delphi%29).